# How to refer to an entire column or row in a variable matrix in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, matrix, reference

I've spent a lot of time looking for a way how I can refer to a range (column or row) in a matrix that I have created in VBA.

A simple example is to loop through 4th row of a 4 by x Matrix to sum columns 1 to 3 for column x.

The below code is the long way to do it:

```
x = 10

Dim Matrix() As Variant
ReDim Matrix(1 to 4, 1 to x)

For c = 1 to x

   Matrix(4, c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Matrix(1, c), Matrix(2, c), Matrix(3, c))

Next
```

I am looking for a way to do it like this without an error:

```
For c = 1 to x

   Matrix(4, c) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Matrix(1, c), Matrix(3, c)))

Next
```

The following error pops up when I try to run it:

`*Run-time error '1004':
Method 'range' of object '_Global' failed*`

Can you please help to fix this, as other workarounds seem to be rather time consuming.

Thanks!

Andy

Comment: Range is not a global function, you either have to call it on the worksheet or activate the worksheet [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)).  In Word VBA, I'm also able to do something like `With Worksheet(..)  ... End With`.  Search that link I gave you for `With wsTarget` to see what I mean.  Maybe you can say `With ActiveSheet`

Comment: I do not have a source of data for my purpose, as I generate a Matrix table using randomly generated variables for a Monte Carlo simulation. What i could do is to declare a string variable for "Matrix(" and ", c)" and have a variable fill in the 1,2,3....... Still, isn't there a way to do this with a range?

Comment: Why do you prefer the second method? And why not just simply add the values instead of falling back to a worksheet.function?

Comment: Because if the matrix turns out to be 50 rows by 50 columns, then i would prefer not to add every cell that needs to be added one by one, therefore 50 difference Matrix(row 1,2,3,...,c).

Comment: @Andy You've said *"then i would prefer not to add every cell that needs to be added one by one, therefore 50 difference Matrix(row 1,2,3,...,c)"*. Well, nobody would, true. You should investigate the concept of nested loops! Then even a 100000 x 100000 matrix will be an easy thing to handle, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As James Poag said, range is not a global function and must be called in association with a worksheet.  If you want to use the `WorksheetFunction.Sum` then you will have to copy your matrix to a worksheet.  In the example below:

1. Create a 4 x 10 matrix of random numbers,
2. Create a new work sheet,
3. Copy the matrix to the worksheet,
4. Use the `WorksheetFunction.Sum` to add rows of the range, and
5. Delete the worksheet added by the VBA macro

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Sub Matrixer()
       Dim x As Long
       x = 10
       Dim matrix() As Double
       ReDim matrix(1 To 4, 1 To x)

       'Generate the matrix
       Dim rowNDX As Long
       Dim colNDX As Long
       For rowNDX = 1 To UBound(matrix, 1)
           For colNDX = 1 To UBound(matrix, 2)
               Randomize
               matrix(rowNDX, colNDX) = Rnd
           Next colNDX
       Next rowNDX

       'Write the maxtrix to a sheet
       'First add a worksheet to do the calculation
       Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
       Dim strName As String: strName = "MATRIXCALC"

       Dim ws As Worksheet
       Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
       With ws
           .Name = strName
       End With

       'Write the maxtrix to the sheet
       'This code was provide/adapted from Chip Pearson's blog at
       'http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx
       Dim Destination As Range
       Set Destination = ws.Range("A1")
       Destination.Resize(UBound(matrix, 1), UBound(matrix, 2)).Value = matrix

       'Use the worksheet function to Sum the range
       Dim RowSum(4) As Double
       Dim rngSum As Range
       For rowNDX = 1 To 4
           Set rngSum = ws.Range("A" & Trim(CStr(rowNDX)) & ":A" & Trim(CStr(UBound(matrix, 2))))
           RowSum(rowNDX) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngSum)

       Next rowNDX

       'Delete the worksheet added by the macro
       'Prevent asking user if it's ok to delete worksheet
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ws.Delete
       'Turn application display alerts back on.
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jamie Ris. I then assume that the pasting of the matrix into excel and using actual cell references are mandatory for this to work and avoid the repetition of 1000x same code. Thanks I will incorporate the pasting. In case there is an easier way (like with the range, or using full column ), I will be more than happy to learn about this.  Thank you!!!